# Amplitude of a signal from it's function

Tags: laser, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

If I have the equation of a light pulse in the form

$$L(ω)=\frac{1}{π}\frac{\frac{1}{2}Γ}{((ω−ω_0)^2+(\frac{1}{2}Γ)^2)}$$

where $\Gamma$ is the linewidth of the pulse and $\omega_0$ is its resonant frequency, how do I find the amplitude of the pulse?

Answer (score 0):

L **is** the amplitude in the Fourier domain.  The actual pulse will have an oscillating term such as $\cos(\omega t)$.  In other words, the Lorentzian L is the envelope of the actual oscillatory field.  Typically the Lorentzian (or a sum of Lorentzians) is used to model spectra.  A more common model of a pulse would be a Gaussian modulated by $e^{i \omega t)$.  Then the amplitude would just be the Gaussian.  Or did I misunderstand the question?  If your detector is not sensitive to phase, then you just see the envelope.